# The issue is caused by a circular import. Django

Tags: django, django-urls, django-apps

**Hello colleagues! I was working in Django project. I have a problem with my urls**

In the project I only have one app within that app, I created my urls file to later import it into the urls of the entire project, but when the server was running, it gave me the following error:

```
The included URLconf 'online_store.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

**My urls.py project**

```
from django.contrib import admin

from django.urls import path, include

urlspatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', include('online_store_app.urls')),
]
```

**And my urls.py of app**

```
#   Dajngo
from django.urls import path
from online_store_app import views

urlspatterns = [

        #   urls site 
    path('home', views.home, name = 'home'),
    path('services', views.services, name = 'services'),
    path('store', views.store, name = 'store'),
    path('blog', views.blog, name = 'blog'),
    path('contact', views.contact, name = 'contact'),
]
```

Comment: Is it your import statement at the start of your first file : 
from django.urls import include ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is just a typo, in both files you need to write `urlpatterns` not `urlspatterns` (there is no s between url and patterns).

Comment: Yes! Thanks bro! I am starting and sometimes I think that they are bigger problems, thank you very much, they make programming something easier and possible

Comment: @AldoMatus I'm glad to help. If you are happy with the answer, please give it an upvote, and click the tick to mark it as accepted.